# Boolean AND and OR operations

Tags: c, binary

Why does the following code output `1`, instead of `0`? `a || b` should give me `1` and `1 && 0` is `0`, right? I don't think logical operations evaluated from right to left.

```
int main()
{
    printf("%d\n", 1 || 1 && 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just an aside: those aren't binary in the sense of bitwise, by the way (they _are_ binary in that the work on two values). They're logical operators. `&` and `|` are the bitwise ones.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`&&` has higher precedence than `||`. (Like how multiplication has higher precedence than addition.)

Comment: And because of this, it's advisable to use parentheses unless the precedence is quite obvious: `printf("%d\n", a || (b && 0));`

Comment: Turns out the answer is correct. If `||` had precedence, then it would be `(1 || 1) && 0`, which results 0. @Mysticial: sorry, wish I could remove the dv.

Answer (score 3):

This is because of operator precedence. In C, the && operator has higher precedence than the || operator so it is evaluated first.

Answer (score 0):

This comes from logical thinking development (boolean arithmetic), maybe even from hardware design using transistor-transistor-logic and lower level hardware languages (VHDL, for instance). We usually do two layer logics, first layer of AND's and second of OR's. The most typical situation being circuit minimization [1].

Typically, you combine input signals combinations as AND-ports inputs, and AND-ports outputs as OR-port inputs.

[1] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circuit_minimization